# How to place four boxes inside a layout?

Tags: android, xml

I want to create this type of layout where in the boxes are of equal shape and are arranged like this:

[image]

I have think of creating two `Linear Layout` with `horizontal` orientation where in I can fit the two boxes. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the code, I have written:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
....
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/share_app_row_one_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/box_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Box #1"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/box_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Box #2"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/share_app_row_two_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/share_app_row_one_container">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/box_3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Box #3"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/box_4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Box #4"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/white"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"

                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>


            </LinearLayout>
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the boxes are not uniform.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have done that using `button` attribute, but the problem is the buttons are not uniform.

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the constraints to reach the goal:

[image]

And the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/boxOneTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/boxThreeTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/boxTwoTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="Box 1" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/boxTwoTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/boxFourTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/boxOneTextView"
            tools:text="Box 4" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/boxThreeTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/boxFourTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="Box 3" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/boxFourTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/boxThreeTextView"
            tools:text="Box 4" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set a drawable like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/box_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/box_ic"
    android:text="Item 0"/>
```